# Bubble in ggplot2 for specific dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data frame from indicspecise R package as below

```
organisms indicator_value R_G1 p_G1 R_G2 p_G2 R_G3 p_G3 ..
A .98. 01 .05. .2. 05 .09. 02
B .98 .05 NA .1. 03 .09. 04
C .98 .02.. 02 .07 NA .2 0.02
```

I want to draw a bubble plot like this "https://ibb.co/Pt7CM7P". can anyone assist me. Thank you for your assistance[image]

Comment: This question is [crossposted](https://www.biostars.org/p/473291/).

Comment: Thank you for mentioning. Is there any restricted policy about it?

Comment: It's not encouraged [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/388946) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159/8245406).

Comment: Also, how have you loaded the data? I am not seeing that data in package indicspecies.

Comment: indicspecies pachage gives only the indicator and P value https://jkzorz.github.io/2019/07/02/Indicator-species-analysis.html. I need to manage it in excel and upload the data as csv file. I am not very efficient in R langauge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bubble plot image you show has relative abundance mapped to size and p value mapped to color, but your data frame only has a single numerical value to map to each point. For illustration, I have mapped this single value to both color *and* size.

The first step is to pivot the data into long format to allow straightforward variable mapping. Doing this correctly is dependent on the precise structure of your original data, so you may have to alter this if you intend to use the code on a different dataframe layout.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -1)

ggplot(df[df$name != "indicator_value",], aes(name, organisms)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value, color = value)) +
  geom_text(data = df[df$name == "indicator_value",],
            aes(label = value), check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "gold") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 10)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(organisms = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C"), class = "factor"), indicator_value = c(0.98, 0.98, 0.98
), R_G1 = c(1, 0.05, 0.02), p_G1 = c(0.05, NA, 0.02), R_G2 = c(0.2, 
0.1, 0.07), p_G2 = c(5L, 3L, NA), R_G3 = c(0.09, 0.09, 0.2), 
    p_G3 = c(0.02, 0.04, 0.02)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df
#>   organisms indicator_value R_G1 p_G1 R_G2 p_G2 R_G3 p_G3
#> 1         A            0.98 1.00 0.05 0.20    5 0.09 0.02
#> 2         B            0.98 0.05   NA 0.10    3 0.09 0.04
#> 3         C            0.98 0.02 0.02 0.07   NA 0.20 0.02
```

Comment: Thank you Allan Cameron, you are right, "The bubble plot image you show has relative abundance mapped to size and p value mapped to color" I am sorry, I am failed to show the data frame. I actually want to mean like R_G1 indicates Group1's relative abundance along with p_G1 indicates the p value of that group which want to show in color on aboudance bubble plot. Thank you very much for giving time here. Please think about the data file in a txt/csv format